# How to use font type Segoe UI for notification emails from Access

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, access

I created an Access web app that sends notifications to Outlook users and would like to use font type Segoe UI in an e-mail section.

From what I read Segoe UI is a owned by Microsoft and requires a license to use. But also I'm aware that it's available in OUtlook.

In Access I used `<font face="font_family">` tags to format the text. But face="segoe" does not work?

How can I accomplish this? Or is this not possible?

I also tried to changing the color of hyperlinks, but this also did not work? Is that impossible also?

Answer (score 0):

```
style="font-family:''Segoe UI'';font-size:14pt;"
```